# Typescript - Conditionally optional generic function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am writing a library where I generate sql statements with parameters. I am hoping I can add a bit of typescript magic to make it so that when an empty list of parameters is provided, I can make that function parameter optional. I am not sure how to accomplish this generically. Here is the basic type:

```js
class Statement<Params> {
    exec(params: Params) { /* do stuff */ }
    all(params: Params) { /* do stuff */ }
    one(params: Params) { /* do stuff */ }
}

const create_stmt = new Statement<{ username: string; password: string }>()
create_stmt.exec({ username: 'bob', password: 'secret' })

const list_stmt = new Statement<{}>()
// What I want is to skip this argument since I know its just an empty object. As expected though, there is a type error: "An argument for 'params' was not provided."
const rows = list_stmt.all()
```

obviously this function would expect `{}` when calling `.all`. My next thought was that an `undefined` arg could be skipped:

```js
type OptionalOnEmpty<T> = keyof T extends never ? T | undefined : T

class Statement<Params> {
    exec(params: OptionalOnEmpty<Params>) { /* do stuff */ }
    all(params: OptionalOnEmpty<Params>) { /* do stuff */ }
    one(params: OptionalOnEmpty<Params>) { /* do stuff */ }
}

const create_stmt = new Statement<{ username: string; password: string }>()
create_stmt.exec({ username: 'bob', password: 'secret' })

const list_stmt = new Statement<{}>()
// this still fails, I have to at the very least, pass list_stmt.all(undefined)
const rows = list_stmt.all()
```

I am hoping someone here has an idea on how I can make this work. Perhaps there is some typescript magic that I can do using tuples? In reality, building out this statement is much more elaborate, I have simplified here to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you missed was wrapping the `extends` into tuples so that it isn't distributive:

```
type Perhaps<T> = [keyof T] extends [never] ? [] : [T];
```

Also, notice that I am now returning tuples instead of `T` or `T | undefined`. That's because now, instead of directly giving the parameter a type, we're going to be using `Perhaps` as the type of all the parameters the function accepts (as rest parameters):

```
class Statement<Params> {
    exec(...[params]: Perhaps<Params>) { /* do stuff */ }
    all(...[params]: Perhaps<Params>) { /* do stuff */ }
    one(...[params]: Perhaps<Params>) { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

When `Perhaps` gives us an empty tuple, then the method accepts no arguments. When it gives us `[T]`, then the type of `params` is `T`.

So now, when `Params` is `{}`, this works:

```
const rows = list_stmt.all(); // okay
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5z1om)

Comment: oh snap! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! One question, is there a reason to prefer `[keyof T] extends [never]` over `keyof T extends never`?

Comment: @andykais It's to prevent distribution of the conditional. Try using something that isn't {} for the generic and see what happens without it.